# Swift: Can I have a protocol that inherits from a protocol and constrains it?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift-protocols

Say I have the following protocols:

```
protocol RateableItem {
   var identifier: String { get }  // placeholder. This could be a lot of properties
   var name: String { get set }
   var rating: Int { get set }
}

protocol RateableItemManager {

    /// get some objects matching query criteria
    func objects(matching query: RateableItemQuery) -> [RateableItem]

    /// get a specific object
    func object(withID identifier: String) -> RateableItem?

    /// persists them
    func save(_ object: RateableItem) throws

    /// deletes the objects.
    func delete(_ objects: [RateableItem])

    /// creates a new object.
    func create() -> RateableItem
}
```

and

```
struct RateableItemQuery {
    let searchPredicate: NSPredicate?  // nil means all
    let sortingBlock: ((RateableItem, RateableItem) throws -> Bool)?
    let groupingSpecifier: (() -> String)?
    init(matching predicate: NSPredicate? = nil,
         sort: ((RateableItem, RateableItem) throws -> Bool)? = nil,
         groupBy: (() -> String)? = nil) {

        self.searchPredicate = predicate
        self.sortingBlock = sort
        self.groupingSpecifier = groupBy
    }
}
```

I can now implement a concrete type of this which returns concrete types that conform to the protocol. The concrete types that are returned are irrelevant to the rest of my code because the rest of the code only cares that they conform to a protocol. This enables me to make 'production' and 'dummy' versions of the models.

Is there a way where I can define this more generally, such as:

```
struct Query<T> {
    let searchPredicate: NSPredicate?  // nil means all
    let sortingBlock: ((T, T) throws -> Bool)?
    let groupingSpecifier: (() -> String)?
    init(matching predicate: NSPredicate? = nil,
         sort: ((T, T) throws -> Bool)? = nil,
         groupBy: (() -> String)? = nil) {

        self.searchPredicate = predicate
        self.sortingBlock = sort
        self.groupingSpecifier = groupBy
    }
}
```

such that

```
struct RateableItemQuery: Query<RateableItem> {}
```

and

```
protocol ItemManager<T> {

    func objects(matching query: Query<T>) -> [T]

    func object(withID identifier: String) -> T?

    func save(_ object: T) throws

    func delete(_ objects: [T])

    func create() -> T
}
```

and

```
protocol RateableItemManager: ItemManager<RateableItem>
```

Because I want to use this API paradigm, but don't necessarily want to constrain anything at the 'base protocol' level, as I would often just be re-writing these method signatures for the various Protocol-types I'd want to work with.

If I'm not mistaken, associated types have to be concrete, making their return types also concrete, and then I can't easily work with protocol types.

Sorry if I didn't speak "canonically".  I hope I was able to convey my intentions.

Could this be what upcoming Swift 5.1 is offering in terms of opaque types, returning -> some ProtocolType ?

Comment: Opaque types is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out Opaque types aren't the answer either.

I solved my problem by making abstract baseclasses for Managers, the Query and QueryResults were generic structs, and the concrete subclasses for the Managers could take and return protocol-based Data types.

```
public struct Query<T> {

    var searchPredicate: NSPredicate?
    var sortingBlock: ((T, T) throws -> Bool)?
    var groupingSpecifier: (() -> String)?

    var results: QueryResults<T>?

    init(matching predicate: NSPredicate?,
         sort: ((T, T) throws -> Bool)?,
         groupBy: (() -> String)?) {

    }
}


public struct QueryResults<T> {

    public enum ChangeType: UInt {
        case insert = 1
        case delete
        case move
        case update
    }

    public struct Section<T> {
        var items: [T]
        var title: String?
    }

    public var sections: [Section<T>] = []

    public func object(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> T? {
        return nil
    }
}

public class AnyObjectManager<ObjectType> {

    public enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case abstractImplementationRequiresOverride
    }

    typealias QueryDidChangeObjectBlock = ((
        _ query: Query<ObjectType>,
        _ didChangeObject: ObjectType,
        _ atPath: IndexPath?,
        _ forChangeType: QueryResults<ObjectType>.ChangeType,
        _ newIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> Void)

    typealias QueryDidChangeSectionBlock = ((
        _ query: Query<ObjectType>,
        _ didChangeSection: QueryResults<ObjectType>.Section<ObjectType>,
        _ atSectionIndex: Int,
        _ forChangeType: QueryResults<ObjectType>.ChangeType) -> Void)

    /// get some objects matching query criteria.  nil means return all
    func objects(matching query: Query<ObjectType>?) -> [ObjectType] {
        fatalError("Abstract implementation.  You need to override this method and provide an implementation!")
    }

    /// get a specific object
    func object(withID identifier: String) -> ObjectType? {
        fatalError("Abstract implementation.  You need to override this method and provide an implementation!")
    }

    /// deletes the objects.  Does it commit that to disk?
    func remove(_ objects: [ObjectType]) {
        fatalError("Abstract implementation.  You need to override this method and provide an implementation!")
    }

    /// creates a new object but does not save it.
    func create() -> ObjectType {
        fatalError("Abstract implementation.  You need to override this method and provide an implementation!")
    }

    /// this is basically to mimic the functionality of a fetched results controller...
    func monitorQuery(_ query: Query<ObjectType>,
                      willChangeBlock: ((_ query: Query<ObjectType>) -> Void)?,
                      didChangeObjectBlock: QueryDidChangeObjectBlock?,
                      didChangeSectionBlock: QueryDidChangeSectionBlock?,
                      didFinishChangesBlock:((_ query: Query<ObjectType>) -> Void)?) {
        fatalError("Abstract implementation.  You need to override this method and provide an implementation!")
    }
    /// and this is to stop monitoring that.
    func stopMonitoringQuery() {
        fatalError("Abstract implementation.  You need to override this method and provide an implementation!")
    }

    public func saveChanges() throws {
        fatalError("Abstract implementation.  You need to override this method and provide an implementation!")
    }

    public func discardChanges() throws {
        fatalError("Abstract implementation.  You need to override this method and provide an implementation!")
    }
}
```